# How to fit a TAR-GARCH model in R

Tags: r, time-series, garch, nonlinear

I'm trying to understand whether it is possible to fit a threshold AR model with a GARCH effect using R. So far, I only found the functions `garchFit` (which also allows to "merge" ARIMA and GARCH models) and `tar`. In my book (by Tsay) I found the code to fit such models on RATS, but I'm asked to use R. If that is impossible, I'd ask to suggest a solution to bypass this problem. 
I'm studying the continuously compounded log-returns of S&P500 index, and I successfully (at least from the tests!) fitted a GARCH model already. This because the series showed heteroskedasticity in the variance. But the plot also shows some leverage effect, so I thought that a TAR (better than a TGARCH) could explain this phenomenon.
Is it reasonable to try merging those two models? Should I leave the GARCH?
Thanks.